# Is it possible to connect image-maps to the slides?

Tags: jssor

In order to define areas of the slides as links to wherever, it would be desirable, if the "usemap" tag could be used for that.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely. Please just try and let me know if there is any problem.